# Lighting record owner part 2

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This post is a continuation of this [Lighting record Owner](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261984/lighting-record-owner/261993?noredirect=1#comment396496_261993)

I did until here, but record-owner ID is coming null while I am trying to set in force:recordData for the user . here is my final code. Thanks in advance.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="ObjectRecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordLoadError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordOwner" type="string" default="{!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId}"/> trying to get owner ID 

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Name,OwnerId"
                      targetFields="{!v.ObjectRecord}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
                      />

    <aura:attribute name="UserObjectRecord" type="User"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordData"
                      recordId="{!v.recordOwner}" <!-- it is coming null-->
                      fields="SmallPhotoUrl"
                      targetFields="{!v.UserObjectRecord}"
                      />

    <img src="{!v.UserObjectRecord.SmallPhotoUrl}" /> <!-- it is not coming-->
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}">
        <lightning:card iconName="standard:account" title="{!v.ObjectRecord.Name}" >
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
                    <lightning:formattedText title="Industry" value="{!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId}"/><br/>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </lightning:card>   
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: where is `{!v.recordOwner}` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: I have edited the question to incorporate the full code.

Comment: Note that you declared `force:hasRecordId` twice in your component declaration, which could cause `recordId` issues

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- you can't set the default value this way -->
<aura:attribute name="recordOwner" type="string" default="{!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId}"/>
```

You can't use a merge field like that for the "default value", as the attribute won't be populated at that point. Instead, when the record loads, you need to set the value to load.

```
<aura:attribute name="recordOwner" type="string" />
```

...

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  fields="Name,OwnerId"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.updateRecordOwner}"
                  targetFields="{!v.ObjectRecord}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
                  />
```

...

```
updateRecordOwner: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.set("v.recordOwner", component.get("v.ObjectRecord").OwnerId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the actual location of the data. Rather than `{! v.recordOwner }`, which doesn't appear to be populated at all, you need to bind into the target object of your first `<force:recordData>` component's `targetFields` attribute for the field whose data you want.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordData"
                  recordId="{!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId}"
                  fields="SmallPhotoUrl"
                  targetFields="{!v.UserObjectRecord}"
                  />
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this, but still the recordId not coming.

Comment: I also tried to use recordUpdated option of force:recordData to get the {!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId} in js controller and set it in new attribute. Even the ID is setting in the attribute, but <force:recordData aura:id="recordData"                 recordId= null here. Please advise if I am doing something wrong here. Much appreciated

Comment: Where are you checking the value of the record Id? `<force:recordData>` loads asynchronously.

Comment: Even I use <force:recordData aura:id="recordData"
                  recordId="{!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId}"
                  fields="SmallPhotoUrl"
                  targetFields="{!v.UserObjectRecord}"
                  /> this is not working

Comment: RecordID I am trying set using this  recordId="{!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId}"  but it is coming null. However, if  I want see in the screen using {!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId} then I can see ID is there. Do I have to convert {!v.ObjectRecord.OwnerId} into string. Please advise